# Proper way to organize myapp/routes/*

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Using latest stable node.js and express from npm, I've created my first express project.

The default generated app defines routes/index.js, which contains a single route that renders the default index view.

I immediately assumed I could add other .js files to the routes/ folder and they would be included. This didn't pan out. Only routes/index.js is ever included. Adding additional routes to routes/index.js works fine.

**What is the proper way to define and organize Express routes, following the structure provided by the express project generator?**

---

The answer, paraphrasing the article at DailyJS:

Given the following routes:

```
app.get('/', function() {});
app.get('/users', function() {});
app.get('/users/:id', function() {});
```

... Create the following files:

```
routes/
├── index.js
├── main.js
└── users.js
```

Then, inside of routes/index.js:

```
require('./main');
require('./users');
```

**For each new group of related routes, create a new file in routes/ and require() it from routes/index.js. Use main.js for routes that don't really fit in the other files.**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I prefer dynamically loading routes instead of having to manually add another require each time you add a new route file. Here is what I am currently using.

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(app) {
    console.log('Loading routes from: ' + app.settings.routePath);
    fs.readdirSync(app.settings.routePath).forEach(function(file) {
        var route = app.settings.routePath + file.substr(0, file.indexOf('.'));
        console.log('Adding route:' + route);
        require(route)(app);
    });
}
```

I call this when the application loads, which then requires all files in the routePath. Each route is setup like the following:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Express'
        });
    });
}
```

To add more routes, all you have to do now is add a new file to the routePath directory.

Comment: Is your first code block in your `app.js` or like `./router/index.js`?