# Nodejs: Writestream on windows machine

Tags: node.js

For some reason when I try to write a file on my localhost (windows 7) the writestream won't open. On a linux machine, it works fine. Is there some type of permissions I need to add in windows?

I'm already running as administrator.

Here is the current method.

```
// Mainfunction to recieve and process the file upload data asynchronously
var uploadFile = function(req, targetdir,callback) {
  var  total_uploaded = 0
      ,total_file;
    // Moves the uploaded file from temp directory to it's destination
    // and calls the callback with the JSON-data that could be returned.
    var moveToDestination = function(sourcefile, targetfile) {
        moveFile(sourcefile, targetfile, function(err) {
            if(!err)
                callback({success: true});
            else
                callback({success: false, error: err});
        });
    };

    // Direct async xhr stream data upload, yeah baby.
    if(req.xhr) {
        var fname = req.header('x-file-name');
        // Be sure you can write to '/tmp/'
        var tmpfile = '/tmp/'+uuid.v1();
        total_file = req.header('content-length');
        // Open a temporary writestream
        var ws = fs.createWriteStream(tmpfile);
        ws.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log("uploadFile() - req.xhr - could not open writestream.");
            callback({success: false, error: "Sorry, could not open writestream."});
        });
        ws.on('close', function(err) {
            moveToDestination(tmpfile, targetdir+fname);
        });


        // Writing filedata into writestream
        req.on('data', function(data,t,s) {
          ws.write(data,'binary',function(r,e){
            total_uploaded = total_uploaded+e;
            var feed = {user:'hitesh',file:fname,progress:(total_uploaded/total_file)*100};
            require('./../../redis').broadCast(JSON.stringify(feed))
          });
        });

        req.on('end', function() {
            ws.end();
        });
    }

    // Old form-based upload
    else {

        moveToDestination(req.files.qqfile.path, targetdir+req.files.qqfile.name);
    }
};
```

Comment: 1. Have you waited for the `'open'` event before calling `write`? 2. Please provide sample code that produces the error.

Answer (score 2):

As your code is running fine on Linux it must be something specific to Windows.

```
var tmpfile = '/tmp/'+uuid.v1();
```

might be your problem. The folder/path structure on windows is different. Try using the `path` module and change your code to

```
var path = require('path');

var tmpfile = path.join('tmp', uuid.v1());
```

The same goes probably to your parameter `targetdir`.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756567/do-you-need-to-use-path-join-in-node-js) related question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the directory. Unless you have a C:\tmp directory (assuming you're running node from the C drive), it doesn't have anywhere to write the tmp file.

You could either create a C:\tmp directory or modify the line

```
var tmpfile = '/tmp/'+uuid.v1();
```

to something like

```
var tmpfile = __dirname + '/tmp/'+ uuid.v1();
```

Note: requires a directory something like *C:\mynodeproject\tmp*