# grunt "Error: Cannot find module '../time/convert' (only on windows)

Tags: windows, node.js, npm, gruntjs

Setup a new angular project under linux.  Committed it to git and cloned it to windows.  Using bower and npm, I managed to get everything loaded, except, I have this one error (only on windows)

A recursive grep for ../time/convert in the project shows me:

```
./node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/mout/date/diff.js:var convert = require('../time/convert');
./node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/mout/src/date/diff.js:define(['./totalDaysInMonth', './totalDaysInYear', '../time/convert'], function(totalDaysInMonth, totalDaysInYear, convert){
./node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/optipng-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/mout/date/diff.js:var convert = require('../time/convert');
./node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/mout/date/diff.js:var convert = require('../time/convert');
./node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/mout/src/date/diff.js:define(['./totalDaysInMonth', './totalDaysInYear', '../time/conve
```

but ls -l shows:

```
$ ls ./node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/mout/time
convert.js  now.js  parseMs.js  toTimeString.js
```

Which says that convert.js is actually there.  Being new to grunt and angular, I'm puzzled where this could be coming from and how to troubleshoot it.

After this I end up getting stuck here:

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.4 server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [watcher]: Pattern ".../test/mock/**/*.js" does not match any file
WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again.
WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again.
```

Wondering if angular work using grunt is just not possible on Windows....

Comment: my guess, the mout library is assuming *nix paths. you could try editing those lines to use [path.normalize](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_p) e.g. `var path = require('path'); var convert = require(path.normalize('../time/convert'));` I haven't actually used this so I can't promise it would work but it's the first thing I'd try

Comment: looks like I might be mistaken and that's unnecessary, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756567/do-you-need-to-use-path-join-in-node-js

Comment: in my case, the same error is when trying to install bower; however, there *is no time/ folder* at the place it should be. There's only a ``time.js`` file containing ``//automatically generated, do not edit! run `node build` instead`` and require calls to ``./time/etcpp``. But still: there is no such folder, only in a ``src`` directory... any ideas?

Comment: meh... a ``bower update mout`` fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution was to quit using windows.  Moved dev work to linux, and no more crazy problems like this.  Oh, and my machine now seems a good deal faster too.