# HTML - Include Javascript in parent directory

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a HTML page and I am trying to include some js files like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

But I keep getting

`Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js".`

followed by

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.js:1`

in the developer console. I am trying some tutorials on angular.js and node.js

**Solved**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21823343/1451512

Comment: What happens when you point your browser to `http://localhost:8080/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js`? Looks like it's returning HTML, perhaps an error page?

Comment: Solved: I was able to use http://stackoverflow.com/a/21823343/1451512 to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You're including `../bower_components/jquery/jquery.js` as a script, so the browser tries to interpret as a script. The reason it finds a `<` is probably because the server can't find a file at that path, and so it returns a 404.

To make sure this is the case, open the developer tools of your browser of choice. Most, if not all browsers have a way to see the requests and their responses. In chrome, you can do this by opening the dev tools and clicking the network tab.