# /bower_components doesn’t load dependencies on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, bower

`/bower_components` doesn’t work.

I get `404` error:

```
GET /bower_components/jquery/jquery.js 404
```

My configuration is as described in Bower documentation and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821773/configure-node-express-to-serve-static-bower-components):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
```

In my .html file I have:

```
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

But there is no `/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js`. There is `\bower_components\jquery\dist\jquery.js`. Did they change the configuration of Bower packages but forgot to change docs?

Comment: If you look in the file system, do you see the file `/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js`?

Comment: @dylants: No, there is no such a path in the file system. `jquery.js` is located here: `\public\bower_components\jquery\dist\jquery.js`. I know I can move `jquery.js` and it will work but it seems that it is not correct, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You should change your script tag to point to the (new) location of jQuery:

```
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

It looks like jQuery has separated the "source" code from the "distribution" code, by providing two directories in their bower component.  It is not recommended that you move things around inside `bower_components` since that directory is generated from the bower install.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, i had accidentally deleted the .bowerrc, causing the bower_components to be saved in the wrong place