# Referencing a parent directory in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, bower

As far as references to directories are concerned, I understand

```
./ = current
../ = parent
```

But I am having a problem referencing my `bower_components` directory in this bit of HTML code. The reference to the `lib` folder works fine but not `bower_components`. What am I missing?

## main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Directory structure looks like this:
[image]

Comment: What's in `server.js`? My guess is that it's implementing more-o-less boilerplate middleware for serving static files (CSS, client-side js etc.) from its `public` directory, but not from `bower_components` one. As for path part, `../bower_components/foo/bar` is quite fine.

Comment: Check (most probably) [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821773/configure-node-express-to-serve-static-bower-components).

Comment: got it. thank you @raina77ow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to `<your server>/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js`

It probably won't work. If your server setup is normal only `public` and the folders below it are accessible from the client side. From the client point of view `public` is the root, there is nothing above that.

As for importing bootstrap, see if you can browse what node is making available in your browser. It's probably hosting the scripts you need to reference on the client side at another url. You might also find the url in  the bower documentation/examples.

You *could* solve this by copying or symlinking the scripts into the public directory, but that would be a bit hackish, save it for if you get completly fed up with finding the intended way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
<script src="contacts/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Just use the full script path