# /dist/handsontable.full.js 404 Not Found with bower

Tags: express, bower, handsontable

I have installed Handsontable as it's shown on [its documentation](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.19.0/tutorial-quick-start.html?_ga=1.48237605.2058706801.1444739479#page-install) using bower:

> bower install handsontable --save

and i added these links to the view.ejs

```
<script src="/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/dist/handsontable.full.css">
```

but i got the follwoing 404 errors in the browser

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/dist/handsontable.full.js"
handson...full.js

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/dist/handsontable.full.css"
handson...ull.css
ReferenceError: Handsontable is not defined in  

var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
```

even when i tried to change links to the absolute file location (project's root as reference):

```
<script src="./bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="./bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css">
```

i still hav the same problem :

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"
handson...full.js
2
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css"
handson...ull.css
ReferenceError: Handsontable is not defined


var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
```

--- EDIT ----

Here is my project structure , i also have the same problem with loading jquery.js

[image]

i was trying all solutions for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821773/configure-node-express-to-serve-static-bower-components) but none of them work.

Comment: can you show us your file structure?

Comment: it's the very standard structure when you create a project with express and install a module with bower.. i will update the question to show my project's structure

Comment: it looks like that express blocks access to all project's folders and only serves all static ressources from the /public folder

Comment: well your index file seems to be in a subfolder so you can try going up a folder in your path: `./../bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js`

Comment: all solutions i've tried about changing the url have the same right result : http://localhost:3000/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js 404 not found, bower_components is exactly under the root , it's not a wrong url which is generated so the problem doesn't come from the urls but perhaps express is making the restriction to only access the /public folder for static ressources i guess

Comment: I'm running a node app with express and don't quite have that problem but i can't help beyond this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
app.use("/bower_components", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));
```

my mistake was to write it like this :

```
app.use("bower_components", express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components')); // this is wrong
```

and in the view it doesn't matter what i wrote

> (./bower_components or ../bower_components).

All these worked for me :

```
<script src="../bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css">
```