# How to use jsTree in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jstree

I have installed [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/) in my `bower_components` (using guidlines in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821773/configure-node-express-to-serve-static-bower-components)) and my jade template looks like this -

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        script(src='/bower_components/jstree/dist/jstree.min.js')
        script(src='/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bower_components/jstree/dist/themes/default/style.css')
        script(src='/javascripts/custom/mytree.js')
    body
        #mytreediv
            ul
                li First item
                li Second item
```

The script `mytree.js` is a script written by me where I initialize the `mytreediv` div element with jsTree. The script looks like this -

```
alert('Test1');
var myfunc = function () {
    alert('Test2');
    $('#mytreediv').jstree();
};
myfunc();
```

Both of the `alert` boxes do appear, so I am quite sure that the script is getting linked properly to HTML. But, the div element doesn't look like it is transformed to jsTree.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the DOM to load, otherwise jQuery won't be able to find the element:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    /* your code */ 
})
```

Comment: Sorry, but that did not work for me. I have the same alert boxes as the previous code; but now, even alert boxes do not appear.

Comment: Do you even load jQuery? It's not in the code you provided. Add it above the `mytree.js` inclusion. Do you have output on your browser console?

Comment: Yes, you were right - I was not loading jQuery. I thought it wouldn't be necessary thinking that jsTree is loading jQuery. Now that I load it in the jade, the alert boxes appear; but the problem with the jsTree still persists.

Comment: I got the jsTree part working - the problem was the order in which I load jsTree and jQuery in jade. jQuery has to be loaded before (which, now I think is the most logical thing to do, in order to allow jsTree to use jQuery).

Comment: I was about to suggest that! Glad to hear I could help out.